# Android upgraded to plugin version 2.1.3 getting No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener error

Tags: android

Just upgraded the plugin version and having this error

> No static method `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` error

I've tried cleaning the project but that didn't work, any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat doubt that is a gradle problem because that is a method of the Android SDK, which is independent of the Gradle Build System

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem, then someone suggested me to upgrade my support library to 24.2.0

Update every support library "com.android.support:xxx:..." on your grade file to  24.2.0.

I think it may sort out your issue too.

PS: Please elaborate your issue with stacktrace and code snippet.